# Why put method is not always idempotent in Asp Net Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, put, idempotent

As far as I know put is idempotent, i.e., applying this method multiple times will be the same as apply it one time. Please consider the following piece of code:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private static List<string> _list = new List<string>();

    public void Put([FromBody]string value)
    {
        _list.Add(value);
    }

}
```

Clearly as you can see from this example, Put method is not being idempotent here and applying it multiple times will result in `_list` having multiple values. Additionally I could implement other idempotent methods like get or delete in the similar manner. How come put method is always idempotent then?

Comment: It *should* be idempotent, but that's just HTTP/RESTful semantics. If you write an implementation that isn't idempotent, then it won't be. Equally there's nothing to stop you writing e.g. a GET that actually deletes data, should you want to do that.

Comment: It's the programmers' responsibility to make sure they are idempotent. If the IDE was so smart, it could write the code on its own, and we would all be unemployed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PUT` *should* be idempotent. If your implementation of `PUT` is not idempotent, then it's in violation of the HTTP specification.

However, that doesn't mean that you are prevented from writing non-conforming implementations.

Technically this is no longer HTTP